# Confusion Matrix with different colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, confusion-matrix

i have a problem. I've created a confusion matrix which looks like this:
[image]

the following code is this one:

```
cm = np.array([[2547,288],[ 255,216]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cmap='BuPu', fmt='g')

ax.set_title('Seaborn Confusion Matrix with labels\n\n');
ax.set_xlabel('\nPredicted Values')
ax.set_ylabel('Actual Values ');

## Ticket labels - List must be in alphabetical order
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['True','False'])
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['True','False'])

## Display the visualization of the Confusion Matrix.
plt.show()
```

this is most likely fine but i want it to look a little bit different like this:

[image]

as you can see, the colors which should be correct are green and the other ones red and aswell i want to show the labels (true positive, true negative, ...). And a label should be for the actual and predicted and for the negative and positive values. So 1:1 as you can see in the photo below.

is there a way i can add the labels and correct the colors in seaborn?
Ty very much for your help !

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a heatmap ? Are you looking to have the red/green colors be dynamic & darker/lighter depending on the size ?

Comment: No the colors should not get darker or lighter after who, these should always be the same color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a heatmap with a unity matrix as data, and the numbers you want as annotation. Use a colormap created as a palette from just two colors (first the color for 0, then the color for 1). Seaborn will take care to use the appropriate text color.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set(style='white')
cm = np.array([[2547, 288], [255, 216]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.heatmap(np.eye(2), annot=cm, fmt='g', annot_kws={'size': 50},
            cmap=sns.color_palette(['tomato', 'palegreen'], as_cmap=True), cbar=False,
            yticklabels=['True', 'False'], xticklabels=['True', 'False'], ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.tick_params(labelsize=20, length=0)

ax.set_title('Seaborn Confusion Matrix with labels', size=24, pad=20)
ax.set_xlabel('Predicted Values', size=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Actual Values', size=20)

additional_texts = ['(True Positive)', '(False Negative)', '(False Positive)', '(True Negative)']
for text_elt, additional_text in zip(ax.texts, additional_texts):
    ax.text(*text_elt.get_position(), '\n' + additional_text, color=text_elt.get_color(),
            ha='center', va='top', size=24)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: confusion matrix via seaborn heatmap]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. Is there an option to add below the numbers e.g. 2547 a label with a small text?

Comment: Thank you. As you can see in the colour of the picture above, there is some text under the numbers. 
So I just want to write True Positive and so on under the numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is masterful.