# How label to the data (not the axes) of the plot of a confusion matrix that displays True Positive, False Positive, False Negative and True Negative

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

I am trying to label the plot of my confusion matrix. The first image below is what my plot currently shows. The subsequent image is what I want to emulate. Here are the features I want to add in order of importance.

1. **Need to have the data labeled like TP = 374  etc.**
2. Can I set background color of xlabels and ylabels?
3. Can I specify the face colors since there are only 4 quadrants?

[image: Current Plot]
[image: The plot I am trying to create]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use seaborn's heatmap with explicit annotations. The colors are defined by the data values in combination with the colormap.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

cm = [[327, 237], [289, 200]]
sns.set(font_scale=3)
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
ax = sns.heatmap(data=[[1, 0], [0, 1]], cmap=sns.color_palette(['tomato', 'lightgreen'], as_cmap=True),
                 annot=[[f"TP={cm[0][0]:.0f}", f"FP={cm[0][1]:.0f}"], [f"FN={cm[1][0]:.0f}", f"TN={cm[1][1]:.0f}"]],
                 fmt='', annot_kws={'fontsize': 30}, cbar=False, square=True)

ax.set_xlabel('Actual Values')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
ax.tick_params(length=0, labeltop=True, labelbottom=False)
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.set_xticklabels(['Positive', 'Negative'])
ax.set_yticklabels(['Positive', 'Negative'], rotation=90, va='center')
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0, 1), 1, 0.1, color='yellow', clip_on=False, zorder=0, transform=ax.transAxes))
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0, 0), -0.1, 1, color='yellow', clip_on=False, zorder=0, transform=ax.transAxes))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap for confusion matrix]

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks a million. I did not think it was even possible to add background colors to the xticklabels and yticklabels.  For anyone else who is interested, unbeknownst to me, there is another answer to this same question with a slicker way to add the text annotations in the plot (i.e. TP=327 etc.)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097754/confusion-matrix-with-different-colors

Comment: Is upvoting usually done in addition to marking the question as answered?? Honestly not sure of the protocol here.